# Showing that $\{X ⊆ R \mid X \neq ∅$ and $∀x∀y((x ∈ X ∧ x < y) → y ∈ X)\}$ has no minimal element.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing

This is Velleman's exercise 4.4.12:

Showing that $\{X ⊆ R \mid X \neq ∅$ and $∀x∀y((x ∈ X ∧ x < y) → y ∈ X)\}$ has no minimal element.

I know that I need to prove: $∃X ∈ \mathcal F(A ⊆ X \land A \neq X)$.

But I don't know what are my givens exactly and how to use "$\{X ⊆ R \mid X \neq ∅$ and $∀x∀y((x ∈ X ∧ x < y) → y ∈ X)\}$" to show "$∃X ∈ \mathcal F(A ⊆ X \land A \neq X)$". Please give me a hint on how to solve this problem i.e. I don't want the full answer.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hint: this can also be written as $I=\{ (-\infty,\infty) \} \cup \{ (a,\infty) : a \in \mathbb{R} \} \cup \{ [a,\infty) : a \in \mathbb{R} \}$. For the moment, take that as given. Then show by cases that if $X$ is in each of these three categories then you can find another set in $I$ contained in $X$. Then prove my hint.

Comment: I apologise for my ignorance, just trying to learn.but could you not do this by deriving a contradiction? By assuming there exists a minimal element? And so X is bound below by that element? Then wouldnt letting x be that create the contradiction?

Comment: @Vaas Indeed, the basic structure is by contradiction: suppose $X$ is a minimal element of what I called $I$. Furnish an element of $I$ contained in $X$. Then $X$ couldn't be minimal.

Comment: @Ian Could you please explain it more thoroughly. I don't understand how did you produce the set $I$. I understand its (the problem) structure and how it could be proved by contradiction but I guess my problem is with the definitions i.e. from the definitions I'm not able to imagine a possible situation regarding the statements.

Comment: I suggest that you elaborate on $\exists X\in\mathcal F(A\subseteq X \land A \neq X)$. What is $\mathcal F$? What is $A$? BTW, “$\mathcal F$ has no minimal element” means that **every element** of $\mathcal F$ is not minimal.

Comment: @Heptapod I did it by noting that your definition says "if $X \in I,x \in X$ and $x<y$ then $y \in X$". Such a thing must be an upper infinite interval. If you still don't understand, play around on a number line on paper a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

For all $r \in \mathbb{R}$, $(r,+\infty)$ is an upper set, i.e. $(r,+\infty) \in \{X \subseteq \mathbb{R} \mid X \neq \emptyset \text{ and } \forall x \forall y((x \in X \land x<y) \to y \in X)\}$.
Let $A$ be a minimal upper set.  Since it is not empty, there is some
$a \in A$.  Now $(a+1, +\infty)$ is an upper set smaller than $A$, i.e. $(a+1, +\infty) \subsetneq A$, a contradiction.