# Show that $\mathcal F=\{X\subseteq\Bbb R|X\neq\emptyset\land\forall x\forall y((x\in X\land x<y)\rightarrow y\in X)\}$ has no minimal element.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, solution-verification

Not a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2443355/showing-that-x-%E2%8A%86-r-mid-x-neq-%E2%88%85-and-%E2%88%80x%E2%88%80yx-%E2%88%88-x-%E2%88%A7-x-y-%E2%86%92-y-%E2%88%88-x-has-n) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3802231/show-that-set-has-no-minimal-elements-under-the-subset-partial-order).

This is exercise $4.4.12$ from the book *How to Prove it* by Velleman $($$2^{nd}$ edition$)$:

Show that $\mathcal F=\Bigr\{X\subseteq\Bbb R|X\neq\emptyset\ \text{and}\ \forall x\forall y\bigr((x\in X\land x<y)\rightarrow y\in X\bigr)\Bigr\}$ has no minimal element.

Here is my proof:

Suppose $\mathcal F$ has a minimal element called $M$. So by definition $M\neq\emptyset$, $\forall x\forall y\bigr((x\in M\land x<y)\rightarrow y\in M\bigr)$, and $\forall X\in\mathcal F(X\subseteq M\rightarrow X=M)$. Since $M$ is not empty we can choose some $m_0\in M$. Since $\forall x\forall y\bigr((x\in M\land x<y)\rightarrow y\in M\bigr)$ we can write $\{y\in\Bbb R|y\geq m_0\}\subseteq M$. Now consider the set $W$ as follows $W=\{x\in\Bbb R|x>m_0\}$. Clearly $W\in\mathcal F$ and also $W=\{x\in\Bbb R|x>m_0\}\subseteq\{y\in\Bbb R|y\geq m_0\}\subseteq M$. Since $\forall X\in\mathcal F(X\subseteq M\rightarrow X=M)$, $W=M$ which contradicts the fact that $m_0\in M$ but $m_0\notin W$ and ergo $\mathcal F$ has no minimal elements. $Q.E.D.$

Is my proof valid$?$

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your proof is valid! Nicely done.

One small note: this didn't need to be a proof by contradiction. You really gave a direct proof that each element of $\mathcal{F}$ is not minimal, so it might be more elegant to structure your proof in this way. That's just a matter of taste, though.

Comment: Thank you very much. :$)$